# member var set to object with unpredictable behavior in js module?

Tags: javascript

I have the js modules defined below (example). This code was working in a standalone test webpage but after I migrated to an MVC app the vars/aliases defined towards the top of the module are resolving as "undefined" when referenced in the module function. However, if I change the reference in the function to the fully qualified object reference then the reference resolves without issue.  Any idea what the issue might be or what is needed for the aliases to resolve successfully?

```
var ns = Acme.Utility.NamespaceManager.CreateNS("Acme.ReportApp");
ns.DailyReport = (function (){

  var globals = Acme.ReportApp.Globals;

  var getDailyReport = function() {
    return{
      AppName1:globals.AppName, //this fails
      AppName2:Acme.ReportApp.Globals.AppName, //this succeeds
      ReportName:'Daily Report'
    };
  }

  return{
    GetDailyReport : getDailyReport
  };

})();

var ns = Acme.Utility.NamespaceManager.CreateNS("Acme.ReportApp");
ns.Globals = (function (){

  var appName = 'Reporting Application';

  return{
    AppName : appName
  };

})();
```

---

I'm using SystemJS to load the modules like this:

```
SystemJS.import('Globals.js')
.then(function(){SystemJS.import('DailyReport.js');})
.then(function(){Acme.ReportApp.DailyReport.GetDailyReport();})
```

When the then() function gets hit:

Acme.Report.App.Globals can be accessed in the final then but Acme.Report.App.DailyReport is undefined. Why would the final then() function have access to Globals but not DailyReport?  Shouldn't the code above load the modules in sequence so by the time the final then() function gets called all modules should be loaded and available?

One interesting note is that the first import can be accessed as expected in the final then() function above. So if I imported DailyReport first then I'd be able to access DailyReport in the final then() function but not Globals. So it appears that maybe I'm doing something incorrectly in the import chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are immediately executing that first function, which accesses `Acme.ReportApp.Globals;`. If that second function hadn't run yet, that won't be defined. Your code is execution order dependent:

```
var globals = Acme.ReportApp.Globals; // <- nothing has defined this
```

Even if `Acme.ReportApp.Globals` is set later on, your `globals` reference will continue to be `undefined`.

I'd recommend you either:

- Make sure your modules are defined in the right order.
- Don't dereference a "module" in your module constructors, only in their methods.
- Use a real module system (CommonJS, AMD, etc).

**Update**:

Thanks for posting your import code as well. That makes things a lot clearer. There is a subtle bug in this code:

```
SystemJS.import('Globals.js')
  .then(function(){SystemJS.import('DailyReport.js');})
  .then(function(){Acme.ReportApp.DailyReport.GetDailyReport();})
```

The second line should have this instead:

```
.then(function() { return SystemJS.import('DailyReport.js'); })
```

...otherwise the Promise chain won't wait for that second import Promise to complete before running `Acme.ReportApp.DailyReport.GetDailyReport();`.

Comment: I'm using SystemJS to load the modules like this:

    SystemJS.import('Globals.js')
    .then(function(){SystemJS.import('DailyReport.js');})
    .then(function(){Acme.ReportApp.DailyReport.GetDailyReport();})

When the then() function gets hit:

Acme.Report.App.Globals can be accessed in the final then but Acme.Report.App.DailyReport is undefined. Why would the final then() load Globals but not DailyReport?  Shouldn't the code above load the modules in sequence so by the time the final then gets called all modules should be loaded and available?

Comment: I added some additional context under the horizontal line in my original post

Comment: this is actually working fine in my standalone app.  seems to be some type of loading/sequence consideration in mvc that i'll need to investigage

Comment: There's definitely a bug in that import code. See my update.

Comment: thanks jacob!  including return as u suggested fixes the issue!